# How to display results from two different tables with the same column names

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT titulo, info FROM htmlcss, php ORDER BY date
```

I get Column 'titulo' in field list is ambiguous
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Include the table name.  If you want titulo from htmlcss:

```
SELECT htmlcss.titulo, info FROM htmlcss, php ORDER BY date
```

You can select both if you want:

```
SELECT htmlcss.titulo, php.titulo, info FROM htmlcss, php ORDER BY date
```

Comment: You're not doing a join in your query, so you could always do two different queries: one from htmlcss, one from php.  I'm guessing you're looking to join those two tables somehow, though.

Comment: Just a side recommendation, I would suggest setting the returned keys for the ambiguous fields too - `SELECT htmlcss.titulo AS html_titulo, php.titulo AS php_titulo, info...` - so that they can be easily accessed from any resultant array.

Comment: Please re-write using explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's question to indicate what, if anything, joins the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.titulo, b.info FROM htmlcss a 
    inner join php b on a.titulo=b.titulo  ORDER BY date
```